# Что правильнее: тире или двоеточие?

Tags: двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

И еще в его душе теплилась робкая надежда: может быть, это отведет беду от них самих.

Answer (score 1):

*И еще в его душе теплилась робкая надежда: **может быть, это отведет беду от них самих.***

**Пояснение**

Здесь ставится классическое **пояснительное двоеточие** со значением раскрытия содержания: робкая надежда (какая именно?).

Интонация (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю) соответствующая: неполное понижение голоса перед увеличенной паузой.

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что тире здесь возможно, если автору захочется вложить несколько иное смысловое наполнение? *...теплилась робкая надежда: может быть, это отведет беду от них самих* (тут непонятно без контекста, что именно **это**, но речь не о том, что надежда отведёт беду). *...теплилась робкая надежда — может быть, это отведет беду от них самих* (тут речь о том, что теплящаяся робкая надежда (она же **это**), может быть, отведёт беду.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Комментарий я дам во втором ответе.

Comment: Это не мнение, просто вопрос) Для меня взаимозаменяемость двоеточия и тире -- одно из 'больных' мест. Если начинаю вертеть в голове такое предложение, мысленно подставляя тот или другой знак, то верчу, пока вообще не перестаю его понимать) Спасибо за ответ, чуть яснее стало!

Comment: Трудная тема. Давайте еще немного добавлю, если есть интерес. При постановке пояснительного двоеточия мы РАСКРЫВАЕМ информацию уже заданной темы, а при постановке тире ПРИСОЕДИНЯЕМ информацию.  Эта пара знаков не изменяет смысл сказанного, но по-разному акцентирует наше внимание. При внимательном прочтении можно уловить разницу и в интонации. Хотя голос понижается в обоих случаях, но пауза значительно короче, а все предложение становится динамичнее. Вторую часть мы именно присоединяем, почти как отдельное предложение. Иногда по одной интонации можно понять, какой знак более подходящий.

Comment: Спасибо. К слову, мне нравится то отношение к двоеточию, какое декларирует Веллер (это вообще его, можно сказать, авторский знак): "Двоеточием можно присоединять подчиненные предложения, обороты и отдельные слова: это более сильная и глубокая связь, чем посредством запятой. «Он вошел: его не ждали». «Он знал жизнь: имел хорошую память». «Жена таится от мужа: и так везде». «Сколько лет он верил: ждал». Допустимы в одной фразе два и более двоеточий последовательно: «В последний раз предупреждаю: оставь ее: ты ее не стоишь: я тебя насквозь вижу»" (Технология рассказа).

Comment: (Хотя, помнится, есть то ли правило, то ли стилистическая рекомендация не использовать два двоеточия подряд при возможности заменить одно на тире: "Он вошёл: его не ждали — обещался быть к пяти").

Comment: Прочитала я статью «Веллер о знаках препинания». Это какое-то оригинальное мышление, авторский подход. А знаки должны быть понятны пользователям языка. Правописание основано на грамматике, а это наука точная, она индивидуального авторства не  приветствует, иначе мы вообще перестанем понимать друг друга.  Авторская орфография возможна как исключение,  но основное письмо построено по законам. Мы очень чувствительны к  стилю и грамматике. Речевые нарушения вызывают у нас отрицательные эмоции, это как бы выпады против нашей культуры (правильность языка, вероятно, можно сравнить с религией).

Answer (score 0):

Если в хотите сказать в чём заключалась надежда, то лучше использовать "тире".

Например: У них оставалась одна надежда: что старик уговорит родителей остаться ещё на день.

А если чем эта надежда являлась, то "двоеточие".

Например: Эта была их последняя надежда-их последний шанс на спасение.

В вашем случае надежда "заключалась" в том, что что-то, отведёт беду от них самих. Тут Надо писать "двоеточие".

Answer (score 0):

**Вместо комментария**

Мы знаем, что присоединительное тире **во всех значениях** может заменять двоеточие, а **интонационно** они тоже похожи:  полное понижение тона перед менее длительной паузой.

Поэтому при выборе знака очень важна **структура предложения** (мы как бы **считываем знаки** с нее).  А структуру выбирает автор, ориентируясь на содержание как предложения,  так и всего текста.

Поэтому здесь уже **готовое авторское решение**, а мы должны «угадать»  его, тем более что контекста у нас, как правило, нет.

Я бы поставила тире в таких предложениях: ***И еще была в  душе надежда** – может быть, это отведет беду от них самих.* Или: ***И еще он надеялся** – может быть, это отведет беду от них самих.*

Таким образом, я сокращаю объем первого предложения, посвященного описанию «надежды», «интонационное предупреждение» уже плохо вписывается в такую структуру. И тогда  первая часть отдвигается **на второй план**, а главное внимание читатель обратит на содержание второй части (на «***это***»)

Так воспринимает текст читатель, а автор должен это иметь в виду, **составляя** текст.